# Migration from PoW to PoA Clique on geth

Tags: poa, import, clique, migration

After reading chapter "Repurposing header fields for signing and voting" at https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-225 I've understood the nonce field of blocks in PoW consensus blockchain is reused for another purpose in PoA Clique consensus blockchain so it makes impossible a direct import of PoW blocks into a PoA Clique blockchain.

Has anybody here managed to migrate blocks of a PoW blockchain into a PoA blockchain ?

Would it be possible to import the blocks of PoW blockchain without importing the nonce ? The nonce of PoA Clique blocks can only be full of 0 or full of f.

Thank you for your attention, I would be glad to read your comments.

Comment: You cannot easily migrate blocks from PoW to PoA since they are missing the validator's signature. You can try replying the transactions if they have the same id. But you might have to fixe some of the differences block rewards, uncle blocks do not exists in PoA.